# How to merge items in an array by specific key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have a JavaScript object that has multiple attributes, and the value of these attributes is an array of items (type, count, senderUserName).

I want to combine the items in these arrays that have the same type while preserving the key that they originally correspond to.

Here is an example of my object with the arrays:

```
{C.J :[
  {"type":"call","count":2,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"},   
  {"type":"email","count":0,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"},
  {"type":"sms","count":1,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"},
  {"type":"sms","count":0,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"},
  {"type":"email","count":6,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"}
],
Will :[
  {"type":"call","count":2,"senderUserName":"Will"},   
  {"type":"email","count":1,"senderUserName":"Will"},
  {"type":"sms","count":0,"senderUserName":"Will"},
  {"type":"call","count":1,"senderUserName":"Will"},
  {"type":"call","count":1,"senderUserName":"Will"},
]}
```

The result I want is:

```
{C.J :[
  {"type":"call","count":2,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"},   
  {"type":"email","count":6,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"},
  {"type":"sms","count":1,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"}
],
Will :[
  {"type":"call","count":4,"senderUserName":"Will"},   
  {"type":"email","count":1,"senderUserName":"Will"},
  {"type":"sms","count":0,"senderUserName":"Will"},
]}
```

I have been playing around with lodash methods to get to my results but without any luck. I think I might have to use a combination of `_.map` and `_.reduce` but don't know how to combine them properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `reduce()` and `forEach()` in pure javascript.

```js
var data = {'C.J' :[
  {"type":"call","count":2,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"},   
  {"type":"email","count":0,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"},
  {"type":"sms","count":1,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"},
  {"type":"sms","count":0,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"},
  {"type":"email","count":6,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"}
],
'Will' :[
  {"type":"call","count":2,"senderUserName":"Will"},   
  {"type":"email","count":1,"senderUserName":"Will"},
  {"type":"sms","count":0,"senderUserName":"Will"},
  {"type":"call","count":1,"senderUserName":"Will"},
  {"type":"call","count":1,"senderUserName":"Will"},
]}
  
result = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(r, e) {
  var ar = [];
  data[e].forEach(function(a) {
    if (!this[a.type]) {
      this[a.type] = a;
      ar.push(this[a.type])
    } else {
      this[a.type].count += a.count;
    }
  }, {})
  r[e] = ar;
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks @nenad-vracar. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

That is, of course, if you have ES6 available and aren't trying to run this client-side in older browsers.

If you're set on lodash -- you can do something like this:

```
var data = {"C.J" :[
{"type":"call","count":2,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"},   
{"type":"email","count":0,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"},
{"type":"sms","count":1,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"},
{"type":"sms","count":0,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"},
{"type":"email","count":6,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"}
],
"Will" :[
{"type":"call","count":2,"senderUserName":"Will"},   
{"type":"email","count":1,"senderUserName":"Will"},
{"type":"sms","count":0,"senderUserName":"Will"},
{"type":"call","count":1,"senderUserName":"Will"},
{"type":"call","count":1,"senderUserName":"Will"},
]}

var combined_data = _.map(data, function(element, key){
  var collapsed_element = [];
  var element_type_hash = {};
  _.each(element, function(record){
    if(element_type_hash[record.type] !== undefined){
      element_type_hash[record.type].count += record.count;
    }   else
    {
      element_type_hash[record.type] = record;
    }
  });
  _.each(element_type_hash, function(element_obj){
    collapsed_element.push(element_obj);
  });

  return collapsed_element;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(combined_data));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oumba4p5/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_.transform()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#transform) to collect the keys into a dictionary, and extract the combined values using [`_.values()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#values):

```js
var data = {
  'C.J' :[
    {"type":"call","count":2,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"},   
    {"type":"email","count":0,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"},
    {"type":"sms","count":1,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"},
    {"type":"sms","count":0,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"},
    {"type":"email","count":6,"senderUserName":"C.J.Rosati"}
  ],
  'Will' :[
    {"type":"call","count":2,"senderUserName":"Will"},   
    {"type":"email","count":1,"senderUserName":"Will"},
    {"type":"sms","count":0,"senderUserName":"Will"},
    {"type":"call","count":1,"senderUserName":"Will"},
    {"type":"call","count":1,"senderUserName":"Will"},
  ]
};

var result = _.transform(data, function(result, value, key) { // transform the original object
  result[key] = _(value)
  .transform(function(merged, obj) { // transform the array of objects
    if(merged[obj.type]) { // if the type key already exists
      merged[obj.type].count += obj.count; // add to count
    } else { // if not
     merged[obj.type] = obj; // the obj will be used for the type property
    }
  })
  .values() // take just the values
  .value();
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the significance of the _(value)? Why write it like that?

Comment: The `_(value)` starts a [lodash sequence](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#chain), and the `.value()` invokes it and extract the actual value.